# Factoring $x^4 + 5x^3 + 4x^2 + 2x - 3$

Tags: polynomials, factoring, quartics

> So I have to factor this polynomial
>   $$x^4 + 5x^3 + 4x^2 + 2x - 3$$

I got $(x^2 + 2x -3)(x^2 + 3x + 1)$

but when I multiplied it, I got a different equation:
$$x^4 + 5x^3 + 4x^2 - 7x - 3$$

I don’t really understand how to find the factors. I only found numbers that could add up to 5 and multiply to -3 but they’re wrong. What did I do wrong and what can I do to fix this?

In the format of: 
($x^2$+ __ x +__ ) ($x^2$ + __ x + __ )
or
$$(x^2 + ax + b) (x^2 + cx + d)$$

Also, how does comparing coefficients help factor this polynomial?

Comment: Are you certain you have the correct coefficients?  According to W|A, this function doesn't seem to factorize cleanly at all.

Comment: @Matthew Daly The Ferrari's method helps. See please my post.

Comment: Do you want to factor it to polynomial with real coefficients, which is always possible, or are you only interested in factors that are  polynomials with rational coefficients, which may not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You must have $bd= -3$ so $b= -3$ and $d=-1$ can not be. You must change the signs.

Write $$x^3:\;\;\;\;a+c= 5$$ $$x^2:\;\;\;\;ac+b+d =4$$ $$x:\;\;\;\;ad+cb =-7$$

and solve this system...

Comment: I made a typo. I got b = - 3 and d = 1

Comment: Assuming $a,b,c,d$ are required to be integers, this method works well (+1) to either find qualifying values of $a,b,c,d$, or show that no such values exist. Without loss of generality, we can assume $b\le d$, hence since $bd=-3$, we must have $(b,d)=(-3,1)$ or $(b,d)=(-1,3)$. In each of the two cases, the system of $3$ equations quickly reduces to a result of no solutions.

Comment: @quasi This method does not help for the first polynomial in $\mathbb R[x].$ See please my post. The way, which I posted helps, but for the first polynomial it quits very ugly.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: Presumably the problem is asking for factorization (if possible) in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, not $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Comment: @quasi Where did you see it? It's not given, which says that we work in $\mathbb R[x].$

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: By the tags (factorinng, polynomials), and the OPs comments, the level is elementary.

Comment: @quasi Firstly, factoring of fourth degree polynomial it's elementary enough. Secondly, I still don't see where was written that we need to work in $\mathbb Z[x].$

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, there must be a typo in the question since it does not factorize.

If you write
$$(x^2 + ax + b) (x^2 + cx + d)=x^4 + 5x^3 + 4x^2 + 2x - 3$$ expanding and grouping terms, we end with
$$(b d+3)+x (a d+b c-2)+x^2 (a c+b+d-4)+x^3 (a+c-5)=0$$ and each coefficient must be zero.

So, trying, we have $d=-\frac 3b$, $c=5-a$ but the remaining equations are nightmares since we get
$$a=\frac{b (5 b-2)}{b^2+3}$$ and what is left to solve  for $b$ is
$$-27-36 b-39 b^2+47 b^3+13 b^4-4 b^5+b^6=0$$ which does not show any obvious roots (in fact, there are two real non-rational solutions).

If you had $b$, then all the other are available.

Comment: We can always factorize all polynomial with degree four above $\mathbb R$ by the  Ferrari's method. See please my post.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg. I think that the problem is with the first polynomial, not the second.

Comment: I know. It quits very ugly. See my comments to my post. Way, which I showed for the second polynomial works also for the first.

Answer (score 0):

The following way always works:
$$x^2+5x^3+4x^2-7x-3=\left(x^2+\frac{5}{2}x-1\right)^2-\left(\frac{x}{2}+2\right)^2=(x^2+2x-3)(x^2+3x+1)=...$$
We can get this factoring by the following reasoning.

For any $k$ we obtain:
$$x^2+5x^3+4x^2-7x-3=\left(x^2+\frac{5}{2}x+k\right)^2-2kx^2-5kx-\frac{25}{4}x^2-k^2+4x^2-7x-3=$$
$$=\left(x^2+\frac{5}{2}x+k\right)^2-\left(\left(2k+\frac{9}{4}\right)x^2+(5k+7)x+k^2+3\right).$$
Now, we need to choose a value of $k$ for which $2k+\frac{9}{4}\geq0$ and $\left(2k+\frac{9}{4}\right)x^2+(5k+7)x+k^2+3$ is a perfect square.

We immediately see that $k=-1$ is valid, but if we don't see it we can write a condition for a perfect square:
$$(5k+7)^2-4\left(2k+\frac{9}{4}\right)(k^2+3)=0$$ or
$$4k^3-8k^2-23k-11=0$$ or
$$4k^3+4k^2-12k^2-12k-11k-11=0$$ or
$$(k+1)(4k^2-12k-11)=0$$ and since $2\cdot(-1)+\frac{9}{4}>0$, we obtain the difference of squares and the needed factoring.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not our polynomial,$$x^4+5 x^3+4 x^2-7 x-3$$

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner It was hint. You can make the similar things for the given polynomial. It works, but it quits very ugly. I am ready to show if someone wants to see it.

Comment: Hello Michael, i think we can make it not!

Comment: No, @Sonnhard. You are welcome to show us your solution. I think, it's impossible by another way. The way, which I wrote it's an unique way, which helps here.

Comment: can you show us how to do this with the given polynomial? I assume you start with $\left(x^2+\frac{5}{2}x+a\right)^2-\left(bx+c\right)^2=x^4 + 5x^3 + 4x^2 + 2x - 3$

Comment: @miracle173 I added something. See now.

Comment: @miracle173 For the given polynomial we need to solve a cubic equation, which gives a very ugly root and a very ugly factoring. Are you sure that you really want to see it?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thank you. I understand now, how to calculate it. But it is not necessary that you do the calculation for the original polynomial.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  But does this method  always work? The 3 degree polynomial in k has always a real root, but the additional condition (the coefficient of x^2 must be positive) must not be met by this root

Comment: @miracle173 If the cubic equation has unique real root, so this root will get a negative coefficient of $x^2$ (by your language  and a positive in my explanation) and we'll get a difference of squares. If the cubic equation has three real roots, so always one of them gets a difference of squares. All this says that this method always helps.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can split the four roots of a quartic into two pairs in three different ways. If you want to factor into two quadratics there are three different possibilities therefore (because the roots of the quadratics will be pairs of the original roots). Your equations, therefore, won't have a unique solution except in special cases. They may have a unique solution in integers, but this will not be readily obtainable by algebraic methods - though it may be identified by using the properties of integers and the fact that the search space is small.

Therefore, when you do a trial factorisation (the difference of two squares method illustrated by Michael Rosenberg is one of the ways to go), you expect to find a cubic which gives three different possibilities.

The factorisation of the quartic is "easy" only when the cubic has at least one "nice" root. Your method seems to depend on having an easy factorisation - most quartics don't have this.

Comment: I checked that the resolvent has an unique real root and it gives a difference of squares and solves our problem. It's very ugly, of course.

Answer (score 0):

$(x^2+ax+b)^2=x^4+2ax^3+a^2x^2+2bx^2+2abx+b^2$

we find:

$a=\frac{5}{2}$

$b=\frac{-9}{8}$

and we get following polynomial with these values:

$x^4+5x^3+4x^2-\frac{45}{8}x+\frac{81}{64}$

We compare this with given polynomial; if:

$x^4+5x^3+4x^2+2x-3=0$

then:

$(x^2+\frac{5}{4}x-\frac{9}{8})^2=\frac{273}{64}-\frac{61}{8}x$

This equation has two real roots ; $x_1≈-4.202$ and $x_2≈0.53$ and two complex roots ; $x_3≈ -0.66-0.95 i$ and $x_3≈ -0.66+0.95 i$, so the factorized form can be:

$(x-0.52)(x+4.2)(x+0.66+095 i)(x-0.66+095 i)$

You can get the same result from Wolfram.